# Cannot run picovoice on linux alpine

Tags: python-2.7, docker, speech-recognition, alpine-linux

I am trying to run picovoice voice detection engine on linux alpine. I am running the python version using the python binding provided by picovoice. I am running the python demo on the linux alpine distribution. I have a docker container running on linux alpine. When I run the command

```
python demo/python/porcupine_demo.py --keyword_file_paths resources/keyword_files/linux/blueberry_linux.ppn
```

I see the error

```
OSError: Error relocating demo/python/../../lib/linux/x86_64/libpv_porcupine.so: __vfprintf_chk: symbol not found
```

Anyone else faced this situation? Is there a way to run picovoice on alpine or is it not supported at all?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `libpv_porcupine.so` depends on GNU's C runtime library, [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc) (judging by the `__vfprintf_chk` symbol).

Alpine uses a different, minimalistic libc implementation, called [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org).
Binaries linked against glibc will normally fail to link against musl libc.

You'll need Alpine with glibc - try using a glibc-enabled Alpine as your base image, such as https://github.com/frol/docker-alpine-glibc.